# Windows loadimage function fails but gelasterror function also returns null

Tags: c++, windows

How can LoadImage return null but GetLastError also returns null - doesn't make sense. Here is a simple program that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
int E;
HICON  ICON;

ICON = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "\\TEMP\\ICONA.ICO", IMAGE_ICON,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
E = GetLastError();
printf("result: %X %d \n",ICON, E );
return; }
```

When I compile, link and run I get:

> `result: 0 0`

Comment: Sorry, the call to LoadImage should have be ... 0.0. not just 0,

Comment: Use a good IDE like Visual Studio, it should stop on these typing errors and give you the right information.

Comment: Thanks for the typing advice but I was looking for help on the LoadImage problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If the typing error solves the problem then delete the question, or you may add an answer yourself and accept it. If the problem persists then edit the question and show updated information.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question was clear but I will restate: LoadImage returned null indicated and error, and subsequent GetLastError also returned null which seems contradictory.

Comment: The typo has nothing to do with it and only occurred when transferring the code to this post. Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. What compiler are you using? Also use a full path name.